# How to hide the cursor completely?

Tags: c, winapi

When I call `ShowCursor(0)` (which by the way, does not take an HWND, this is weird), the cursor is hidden, but when I do a special action, for example resizing the window or drag-and-drop a file, the cursor corresponding to this action appears. I don't want to see the cursor whatever action the user is doing. If you wonder why, it's because I'd like to draw it with OpenGL.

I have a popup and layered window:

```
#define UNICODE
#include <windows.h>
#include <dwmapi.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK wnd_proc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp){
    switch(uMsg){
        case WM_CREATE: return 0;
        case WM_NCHITTEST: return HTBOTTOM;
        case WM_DESTROY: PostQuitMessage(0); return 0;
        default: return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wp, lp);
    }
}

HDC hDC; HGLRC hRC;

int main(void){
    WNDCLASSEX wcx = {};
    wcx.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcx.lpfnWndProc = wnd_proc;
    wcx.lpszClassName = L"Win32Class";
    wcx.style = CS_OWNDC | CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcx.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(0x00000000);
    wcx.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    RegisterClassEx(&wcx);

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_ACCEPTFILES | WS_EX_LAYERED, wcx.lpszClassName,
        L"Win32Window", WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE, 50, 50, 800, 400, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd, RGB(200, 0, 200), 0, LWA_COLORKEY);
    ShowCursor(0);

    /*DWM_BLURBEHIND blur = {0};
    blur.dwFlags = DWM_BB_ENABLE | DWM_BB_BLURREGION;
    blur.fEnable = 1;
    blur.hRgnBlur = CreateRectRgn(0, 0, -1, -1);
    DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow(hWnd, &blur);*/

    MSG msg; while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)){
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

This is a truncated part of my test file. OpenGL is not included, but I just need to know how to delete the cursor.

If you compile and execute it, you can see that when your cursor is on the window, it is not visible, but when you resize the window the cursor appears, same as when you drag-and-drop a file.

Comment: I don't think it matters, but im using C

Comment: Showing the code you have generally helps. Not all of it, just the smallest amount that still duplicates the error you're having. See [ask] and [example]. I'm not a C or a winapi guy, so I can't help with your actual problem. This is just advice to improve the question so you can get an answer faster.

Comment: goto EDIT #2; for the code

Comment: Resizing and/or drag-drop runs on own message loop.

Comment: @linternetsansfil the cursor has an internal counter which `ShowCursor()` increments and decrements. The cursor is visible when the counter is > 0. As user2120666 said, resizing a window and drag-and-drop are modal operations that run their own message loops, and increment/decrement the cursor counter accordingly. Try calling `ShowCursor(0)` multiple times to decrement the counter < 0, so that the modal loops don't increment the counter > 0.

Comment: @linternetsansfil [You should implement custom cursors as resources. Rather than create the cursors at run time.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/using-cursors#creating-a-cursor) You can [intercept the `WM_SETCURSOR` message and set your customer cursor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/setting-the-cursor-image) instead of hiding system default cursor.